# Radius of $n^\rm{th}$ orbit of an atom in terms of Bohr's Radius

Tags: atomic-physics, measurements

Bohr's Radius$=0.529$ Angstroms

My book says that the radius of $nth$ orbit of any atom can be calculated by:

$$r=n^2 a_o$$ where $a_o$ is Bohr's Radius.

But I think it should be given by following relation;

$$r=\frac{n^2}{Z}a_o$$

Because $n$ and $Z$ are the factors which change from orbit to orbit and atom to atom respectively in the following equation:

$$r=\frac{n^2 h^2}{4 \pi^2 m Z e^2}$$

Comment: There are no such things as atomic orbits with Bohr radii. That's an old model that was known to be wrong when it was proposed... they just didn't know, yet, how to do it better. The only question is why we are still teaching this? It's not like we are teaching epicycles as preliminaries to Kepler orbits, are we? Having said that, yes, you need the nuclear charge in there, if you want to talk about anything by hydrogen.

Comment: @CuriousOne do you mean "...anything **but** hydrogen."??

Comment: Apologies, yes, that's what I meant. Anything but hydrogen requires that we account for the nuclear charge.

Comment: @CuriousOne that's painful for us students too to still read these old rejected theories along the modern and more accurate ones. I agree with you that students should not be taught old theories unless new theories depend on old theories. Science is inventing new theories and formulas and course of each grade is increasing just as someone is trying to compress his garbage into a filled up bin without throwing old garbage out.

Comment: Exactly. Absolutely nothing in quantum mechanics depends on Bohr's model. It's historically somewhat interesting, but pedagogically it's a waste of everybody's time. It follows a "Let me teach you something that is 100% wrong so I can teach you an 80% correct thing one year later!" scheme. Hopefully we will stop this and teach atomic physics correctly in the future. One doesn't have to understand quantum mechanics to learn what atoms really look like, especially not in high school.

Comment: @CuriousOne I'm not sure how I feel about teaching Bohr's model, but I think it's inaccurate and scientifically unproductive to call it "100% wrong."  Is it the best model we have?  No.  Is it complete garbage?  I certainly don't think so.

Comment: @joshphysics: So are you also teaching students epicycles? They are about as correct as the Bohr model. How about the phlogiston? Newton's corpuscular light theory? Actually, somebody is... otherwise I wouldn't have to explain about three times a day that quanta are not particles and that it's called "quantum mechanics" and not "particle mechanics" for a reason. There is a real problem here, even if you think that I am just nitpicking.

Comment: @CuriousOne No I am not, and I think I made it quite clear that I wasn't sure how I felt about teaching it.  I agree there is a problem, but again, I don't think using hyperbolic characterizations is scientifically productive.  That is the point that I think may have been missed.

Comment: Fair. I like a little drama in the way I am expressing things. I think we can agree that some of what goes for physics education these days simply hasn't quite caught up to the 21st century, yet.